# Is there a way to add multiple new items using Rails Turbo Frames?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo-frames

I am trying to link a button to insert a form for a new item. I want to be able to add a new form for each button click using turbo frames. I am having trouble incrementing the id of each frame so a new turbo frame is added instead of just replacing the old one. I do not want the data to save in my database until the user is done adding items and it is validated.

On my new bulk items page...

```
<%= button_to 'Add One', new_item_path,
          data: { turbo_frame: dom_id(item.new)}, method: :get %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(item.new) do %>
<% end  %>
```

On my new item page...

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(item.new) do %>
  <%= simple_form_for [@item] do |f| %>
  <% end %>
<% end  %>
```

I saw a post that claimed success using this...

```
new_item_#{params.fetch(:index) + 1}
```

I have tried integrating it but get the same error 'param is missing or the value is empty: index', which I'm stuck on trying to pass in :index. How can I increment the index across both frames?

Comment: The [dom_id](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RecordIdentifier/dom_id) helper will turn each passed in `Item.new` into the same id: `new_item`. The id has to be unique for turbo to correctly swap the button with the form.

One solution can be to add a unique identifier as a prefix option. Are you iterating over list to display each "Add one" button?

Comment: I am not iterating over a list. I was just trying to use the same button to keep injecting empty forms. Do you mean I have to place the add new button inside the turboframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single "Add new" button, you could insert multiple new forms with the turbo stream [append](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/streams#append) action.

As the **new** method in the controller responds to an incoming turbo stream request, you could tweak the response.

```
<%# new.turbo_stream.erb %>

<%= turbo_stream.append "items" do %> 
  <%= render partial: "items/form", locals: {item: @item} %>
<% end %>
```

The new form partial will be injected where you have defined the `"items"` id.

```
<%= button_to 'Add One', new_item_path,
          data: { turbo_frame: dom_id(item.new)}, method: :get %>
    
<li id="items">
 <!-- the injected forms will come be injected here -->
</li>
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. I will give it a shot today, thank you, Thomas!